# Biblatex: Writing the output of \thefield{...} to a file

Tags: biblatex, expansion, write

1. Short question: in Biblatex, how do I print the (string) field contents to a file?  When processing an entry I would like to do something like this:

`\write\file{\thefield{userc}}% the file contents is wrong (unexpanded macros here)`

I would like to write to the file the final text, as printed out by \typeout{}:

`\typeout{\thefield{userc}}% outputs "REF1,REF2", etc - I do see the text I need`

For my entries the field "userc" contains comma separated lists of type "REF1,REF2,...". The result of \write is wrong and I am at a loss how to get the macro properly expanded.

I would like to have "REF1 REF2" in the file to generate there commands like \addtocategory{REF1}{KEY}, \addtocategory{REF2}{KEY}) and input the file later where needed.

2. Explanation of what and why is being tried. I am trying to produce the list of citations to my works. Currently I have all the citing bibliography entries equipped with the fields

```
@<entrytype>{KEY,
            RELATED={REF1,REF2}, 
            RELATEDTYPE={set}
            }
```

where REF1,REF2 are the keys of the items which are cited in the work KEY. This works  after adding a suitable macro

```
\newbibmacro{related:set}[1]{%
     %...
    \typeout{\thefield{userc}}% outputs "REF1, REF2", etc - OK
    \write\f{\thefield{userc}}% fails 
    }
```

(the idea found online) and produces the list of bibliography items followed by items citing them. But now I need to organize this in the opposite way (list of works followed by their citations) and keep, if possible, the current structure of the BiB file. I am no expert; any help is welcome.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! It would be good if you provided a compilable example that we can just copy-paste.  But try `\protected@write` instead of `\write` (just guessing).

Comment: Many thanks Pheylipe, `\protected@write` worked well. Curiously enough, `\immediate\write` did not (this is what I tried from the beginning; maybe done something wrong).

Comment: My guess for `\protected@write` is because you said `\typeout` works, and `\typeout` is a `\write` with (a kind of) protection, so `\protected@write` should work.  But I don't really know BibLaTeX, so I don't what `\thefield` does.  If moewe's answer solved your problem, please mark his answer as accepted

Answer (score 2):

### `\immediate\write`

One option to write `\thefield` is to wrote `\immediate`ly. If you say `\write`, the argument will be written out at a slightly later point when the page is shipped out and not at the point you say `\write` (which is extremely convenient if you need to get page references right, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/103944/35864). Unfortunately, `\thefield` won't be available at that later point any more and the write operation will not result in the desired outcome. If you use `\immediate\write` the data is written out immediately when the data is still available.

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[style=authoryear, backend=biber]{biblatex}

% define and open file
\newwrite\myfile
\immediate\openout\myfile\jobname.myf\relax

% close file at end of document
\AtEndDocument{\immediate\closeout\myfile}

\AtEveryBibitem{\immediate\write\myfile{\thefield{volume}}}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
\cite{sigfridsson}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

### `\protected@write`

Alternatively, you can use `\protected@write` as suggested [in the comments](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/553356/biblatex-writing-the-output-of-thefield-to-a-file#comment1396987_553356) by [Phelype Oleinik](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/134574/phelype-oleinik), which is probably a bit safer. With `\protected@write` the data will be written later, when the page is shipped out, but it will be expanded beforehand so that we still print the right thing.

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[style=authoryear, backend=biber]{biblatex}

% define and open file
\newwrite\myfile
\openout\myfile\jobname.myf\relax

% close file at end of document
\AtEndDocument{\closeout\myfile}

\makeatletter
\AtEveryBibitem{\protected@write\myfile{}{\thefield{volume}}}
\makeatother

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
\cite{sigfridsson}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

In both cases, the `.myf` file contains

```
19
```